# How to write awk -F commands

Tags: variables, unix, awk

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | awk ' /Info/, /<\/Body>/ {print $0}' | while read line; do

    file=`awk -F '>' "{print $4}"`

    echo "$file"

done
```

Basically the `file` input file has some information removed in the first line of awk. Now what I'm trying to do is find a variable using `awk -F` and print what comes after the `>` which is the 4th field. Now I can not just search for the `>` because the file has 100s of them because it's html.

ok maybe someone can answer this so when i run the file now it does not look at the forth field however it just removes all of '>' which is not the goal i am trying to locate the field that comes after the 3 '>' so that would be field 4 but thats not what im getting? any help would be great!

Comment: What input is `awk` supposed to be operating on? `$4` is being expanded by the shell since you wrap the awk script in double quotes. There's no reason to capture the `awk` output in a variable just to `echo` it.

Comment: its in a while read line; do so basically what I have is an input with a ton of text that i am sorting so i am trying to take the 4th field that which comes after the 3rd '>' and saving that to a variable and printing that variable

Comment: Do you perhaps want  `awk "/>/{print $4}"`.  Just a guess from your question.

Comment: there is a big difference between `awk -F ...` (fieldSep) and `awk -f ...` (code-in-file) Please update your subject line for the `-F or -f` of your concern. AND sorry, but the rest of your Q is rather hard to follow. Show some inputs (file or strings) and then required output from that input. Good luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the *full* code instead of just a random snippet then?

Comment: defiantly need fieldsep -F, see if that helps i add more code thats about all i got so far because of the awk statement

Answer (score 3):

AWK requires 2 parts

1. Options
2. File to work on

In your example, you have given options i.e. delimiter, what to print, but you have not mentioned which file to work with

Try this

1. On the command prompt

   ```
   cat file | awk -F ">" '{print $4}'
   ```
2. In script

   ```
   result=`cat file | awk -F ">" '{print $4}'`
   echo $result
   ```

For the text file as "file" containing data as

```
a>b>c>d>e>f
```

Both the above will display 'd'.

Comment: That is a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). **awk** takes a file name to read as an argument. This is fine: `result=\`awk -F '>' '{print $4}' file\``

Comment: see i can get it  print everything after the 4th field but i need it to print the 4th field and thats it...